# Getting single node in Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I am trying to get a single object using the `.child()` method however it returns with a `.key` and `.value` array of objects instead of giving me 1 object with all the keys and values. For example:

[image]

Here it is giving me an array of objects. However, if I use a query I will get an array of 1 objects that will return data like this: 
[image]

How can I get a single value in the form of the second picture?

Here is the code:

```
let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config)
let db = app.database()

export default {
  name: 'hello',
  firebase: {
    businesses: db.ref().child('3021')
    // businesses: bdRef.orderByChild('title').equalTo('Feather Animation Wood Carving Supplies') // Code for the bottom picture
  },
  components: {
    'card': Card
  }
}
```

Comment: So let me see if a understood your problem, you want to get only one object with the `.key` and `.value`? Or do you want just one full businesses whose `.key` == "3021"?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem until I realised I needed to add `asObject: true` to my binding as it otherwise puts the results into an array.